# What exactly does this block of statements do in Python?

Tags: python

Im a newbie to python , and I came across this particular code snippet to calculate the greatest slice in an sequence, however I simply cant seem to understand  the following code

```
best = A[0] 
for size in range(1,n+1): 
   cur = sum(A[:size]) 
   for i in range(n-size): 
      cur += A[i+size] -= A[i] # <- what happens here?
      best = max(best, cur)
```

Any idea on how the code functions and with that line in particular would be helpful!

Comment: `… += … -= …` as a syntax error in Python.

Comment: do you have the source for this code?

Comment: @Levon,   I copy pasted the source from an ebook http://www.apress.com/9781430232377

Comment: It doesn't look fixed to me. Also, the comment character in Python is `#`.

Comment: That line in particular would be helpful if you wanted your code to not run because of a syntax error.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, habits die hard, I come from a Java background!

Comment: @Wooble, well I copy pasted exact source code

Comment: Then I suggest switching to a book where the author bothered testing their code.

Comment: It looks vaguely like they're trying to implement Kadane's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: That line should actually say `cur += A[i+size] - A[i]`. Seems strange to include this in an algorithms book though as this is a quadratic-time algorithm for a problem that can be solved in linear time.

Comment: @interjay: Thats most probably right! It is indeed a quadratic solution , the author does provide a solution for a linear time approach.

Comment: Yeah maybe the code was wrong, I guess but then again Im a noob and the down vote was uncalled for IMO :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the error in your code is an extra `=`. Working code:

```
n = len(A)
best = A[0] 
for size in range(1,n+1): 
   cur = sum(A[:size]) 
   for i in range(n-size): 
      cur += A[i+size] - A[i] # <- what happens here?
      best = max(best, cur)
```

The outer for loop creates larger and larger slices, starting with `size` set to 1. Then `cur` is set to the sum of the first `size` items of `A`.

In the inner loop, this slice is "moved" to the right by adding the value just to the right of the slice (`A[i+size]`) and subtracting the first value of the slice (`A[i]`).

Finally `best` is set to whichever is larger of the newly computed sum and the largest value found so far.

In the end, `best` contains the largest sum. Unless `A` contains negative values, the answer is trivial: `sum(A)`.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that there's a bug: The leftmost slice is not counted, except for slice size 1 (`best = A[0]`). So if `A = [4, 3, 2]` it outputs `5` instead of `9`. Fix by adding a `best = max(best, cur)` line above the inner for loop.

Comment: thanks mate! Python can look weird while coming from another language! Hence the doubt! :)

Answer (score 2):

In general the expression would be evaluated left to right before making the final assignment.

However, I don't believe this is valid syntax - do you have the source for this code?

This simple code fails:

```
In [246]: a = 5
In [247]: b = 10
In [248]: c = 0

In [249]: c += a -= b
  File "<ipython-input-249-67e83b5a3545>", line 1
    c += a -= b
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You could try breaking this line into two separate statements:

I.e.,

```
cur += A[i+size] -= A[i]
```

becomes

```
A[i+size] -= A[i]

cur += A[i+size]
```

Assuming you faithfully copied the code, some authors do not test the code included in the final copy, so I suspect an error where an operator was mangled (in particular `-=` could be some other operator, e.g., `-`)

By the way, I checked the **errata** for the book [here](http://www.apress.com/9781430232377) (at the bottom of the page). It doesn't list this error, you might consider submitting it to fellow readers.

Comment: ,will do, thanks for looking at it !:)